# what is equivalent of X509EncodedKeySpec in C#

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, jwt, x509certificate2

I'm trying to port a piece of Java code into .NET that takes a Base64 encoded string, converts it to a byte array, and then uses it to make a X.509 certificate to get the modulus & exponent for RSA encryption.
This is the Java code I'm trying to convert:

```
byte[] externalPublicKey = Base64.decode("base 64 encoded string");
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(externalPublicKey);
Key publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
RSAPublicKey pbrtk = (java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey) publicKey;
BigInteger modulus = pbrtk.getModulus();
BigInteger pubExp = pbrtk.getPublicExponent();
```

I have been trying to figure out the best way to convert this into .NET. So far, I've come up with this:

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("base 64 encoded string");
X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2(bytes);
RSA rsa = (RSA)x509.PrivateKey;
RSAParameters rsaParams = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
byte[] modulus = rsaParams.Modulus;
byte[] exponent = rsaParams.Exponent;
```

Which to me looks like it should work, but it throws a CryptographicException when I use the base 64 encoded string from the Java code to generate the X509 certificate. The exact message I receive is:

Cannot find the requested object.

Is Java's X.509 implementation just incompatible with .NET's, or am I doing something wrong in my conversion from Java to .NET?

Comment: Have you tried X509Certificate2.ImportData? Check [the second code sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: You have a SubjectPublicKeyInfo, not a whole Certificate. .NET doesn’t have inbox API to read those directly.

Comment: Java and .NET support different standards. Java's X509EncodedKeySpec is really a SubjectPublicKeyInfo object from the X.509 standard. .NET supports an XML standards for exchanging public and private keys. In my opinion it's much easier to write Java code to export public keys in this XML format than to write C#/.NET code to import a SubjectPublicKeyInfo. See for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33576188/238704) answer for exporting a private key in this format. You can modify for a public key by dropping all the private key components.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Core 3.0 and up there is the [ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importsubjectpublickeyinfo?view=netcore-3.1) method to import such keys directly.

The code is as follows:

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("encoded key");
var rsa = RSA.Create();
rsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(bytes, out _);
var rsaParams = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
```

Answer (score -1):

forexample

```
            var subjectPublicKeyInfo = new SubjectPublicKeyInfo(your bytes);
            var publicKey = subjectPublicKeyInfo.GetPublicKey();

            using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                RSAParameters parameters = new RSAParameters()
                {
                    Modulus = publicKey.Item1,
                    Exponent = publicKey.Item2
                };
                rsa.ImportParameters(parameters);
                /*
                do something
                */
            }
```

class SubjectPublicKeyInfo and class DER

```
        /// <summary>
        /// DER解析
        /// </summary>
        public class DER : IDisposable
        {
            private bool disposedValue;
            private BinaryReader reader;

            public DER(byte[] bytes)
            {
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
            }

            public bool CanRead => reader.BaseStream.Position < reader.BaseStream.Length;

            private ValueType ReadType()
            {
                return (ValueType)reader.ReadByte();
            }

            private int ReadLength()
            {
                int length = reader.ReadByte();

                //检查第7位是否是1，如果是，则指示该内容长度大于127字节，则此字节6-0为实际的内容占用的字节
                if ((length & 0b10000000) == 0b10000000)
                {
                    //获取长度字节的长度
                    int count = length & 0b01111111;
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[count];

                    //指向内容的长度
                    reader.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                    //翻转顺序
                    Array.Reverse(bytes);
                    length = LengthBytesToInt(bytes);
                }

                return length;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// 根据文档显示，长度不应该超过 256^126 ，即两个字节
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="lengthBytes"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            private int LengthBytesToInt(byte[] lengthBytes)
            {
                if (lengthBytes.Length > 2)
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"length {lengthBytes.Length} too big.");
                int value = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < lengthBytes.Length; i++)
                {
                    value = (value << 8) | lengthBytes[i];
                }
                return value;
            }

            public ValueTuple<ValueType, byte[]> ReadValue()
            {
                ValueType type = ReadType();
                byte[] value = new byte[ReadLength()];
                reader.Read(value, 0, value.Length);
                ValueTuple<ValueType, byte[]> wrapper = new ValueTuple<ValueType, byte[]>(type, value);
                return wrapper;
            }

            public enum ValueType
            {
                BOOLEAN = 0x01,
                INTEGER = 0x02,
                BIT_STRING = 0x03,
                OCTET_STRING = 0x04,
                NULL = 0x05,
                OBJECT_IDENTIFIER = 0x06,
                UTF8String = 0x0c,
                PrintableString = 0x13,
                TeletexString = 0x14,
                IA5String = 0x16,
                BMPString = 0x1e,
                SEQUENCE = 0x30,
                SET = 0x31
            }

            protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (!disposedValue)
                {
                    if (disposing)
                    {
                        reader.Dispose();
                    }
                    disposedValue = true;
                }
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                Dispose(disposing: true);
                GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 兼容 Java X.509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo DER
        /// </summary>
        public class SubjectPublicKeyInfo
        {
            private DER der;
            private readonly byte[] RSA_OID = new byte[] { 0x2A, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xF7, 0x0D, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01 };

            public SubjectPublicKeyInfo(byte[] derBytes)
            {
                der = new DER(derBytes);
            } 

            /// <summary>
            /// 获取公钥
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns>modulus and exponent 返回模数和指数</returns>
            public ValueTuple<byte[], byte[]> GetPublicKey()
            {
                //获取主序列
                var wrapper1 = der.ReadValue();
                if (wrapper1.Item1 != DER.ValueType.SEQUENCE)
                {
                    throw new InvalidDataException();
                }
                var sequence1 = new DER(wrapper1.Item2);
                var wrapper2 = sequence1.ReadValue();

                //检查第一个结构体是否存在
                if (wrapper2.Item1 != DER.ValueType.SEQUENCE)
                {
                    throw new InvalidDataException();
                }

                var sequence2 = new DER(wrapper2.Item2);
                var wrapper3 = sequence2.ReadValue();
                if (wrapper3.Item1 != DER.ValueType.OBJECT_IDENTIFIER)
                {
                    throw new InvalidDataException();
                }

                if (Enumerable.SequenceEqual(wrapper3.Item2, RSA_OID) == false)
                {
                    throw new InvalidDataException();
                }

                var wrapper4 = sequence1.ReadValue();
                if (wrapper4.Item2.First() != 0x00)
                {
                    throw new InvalidDataException();
                }

                //这里有个不明意义的0x00
                var sequence3 = new DER(wrapper4.Item2.Skip(1).ToArray());
                var wrapper5 = sequence3.ReadValue();
                if (wrapper5.Item1 != DER.ValueType.SEQUENCE)
                {
                    throw new InvalidDataException();
                }

                var sequence4 = new DER(wrapper5.Item2);
                var wrapper6 = sequence4.ReadValue();
                if (wrapper6.Item1 != DER.ValueType.INTEGER)
                {
                    throw new InvalidDataException();
                }
                var integer1 = wrapper6.Item2.First() == 0x00 ? wrapper6.Item2.Skip(1).ToArray() : wrapper6.Item2;

                var wrapper7 = sequence4.ReadValue();
                if (wrapper7.Item1 != DER.ValueType.INTEGER)
                {
                    throw new InvalidDataException();
                }

                var integer2 = wrapper7.Item2;

                return new ValueTuple<byte[], byte[]>(integer1, integer2);
            }
        }
```